# How can I use PDF 1.6 documents in Perl's CAM::PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf

I am running into some problems using [`CAM::PDF`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CAM::PDF) with PDF documents which are `%PDF-1.6`

Is there a way to convert those into 1.3? (preferably a free batch-like way...)

What I am currently doing is print the files using the free [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/). The resulting PDF file is `%PDF-1.3`. However, it would take me forever to convert lots of documents.

Comment: `CAM::PDF` outputs %PDF-1.4 files, and can read %PDF-1.5 files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Ghostscript to the job:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -sOUTPUTFILE=out.pdf -dBATCH in.pdf
```

Comment: I finally tried this solution and with a 3,700 Kb %1.4 pdf doc, the converted version has 14,744 Kb! Am I doing something wrong? I used gswin32 8.70

Comment: In my experience the converted documents were bigger than than the originals but not as extremely as in your case (arround 150% to 200% of the original size). As I don't  know the exact characteristics of your documents I can't judge on what the problem actually is but there must be something in your documents which can't be expressed efficiently in PDF 1.3 as I can't see any obvious mistake on your side.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF14Deltas.pdf - Reference documentation of the changes between PDF version 1.3 and 1.4.